# How do I improve the accuracy of the OCR text from Tesseract?

Tags: java, android, android-ndk, ocr, tesseract

I created a basic app for recognizing text using the Tesseract API from Google and integrated it with my camera app. It works fine but the only problem is the accuracy, as sometimes the text is recognized as a random set of characters and I guess the accuracy is about 50 percent.

Further, when it tries to scan more than four words in an image, the app crashes.

```
String ocrText = baseApi.getUTF8Text();
baseApi.end();
```

where `baseApi` is the object of the Tesseract API class.

Do I need to use a different data structure to save the recognized text or is there some other reason why more than four words don't get recognized?

Comment: All you need is better OCR engine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tesseract API class provides a [isValidWord](http://zdenop.github.com/tesseract-doc/group___advanced_a_p_i.html#ga2c06caf08c9a8aa97a08a2de2f6200df) Method to check if the string is a valid word. You can use this to check the recognized characters. This will increase the accuracy of the output.

I am developing using Tess4j  Which is a Java JNA wrapper for tesseract-ocr, and it gives quite good results after checking.

Inaccurate results might be due to the text size, check [this](http://code.google.com/p/tesseract-ocr/wiki/FAQ) out. It says "Accuracy drops off below 10pt x 300dpi, rapidly below 8pt x 300dpi."

Further, not being able to detect more than 4 words depends on a lot of factors, what kind (with how many features) of test image, the size of the image, platform etc.

Comment: Thanks but i wanted to know how can we improve the recognition ?
Like for instance if you see the project uploaded by Robert Theis at https://github.com/rmtheis/android-ocr then you can see he has used image enhancement algorithms and even though he uses the same Tesseract API as mine the recognition rate is higher

Comment: Oh of course, image pre-processing would increase the accuracy of OCR engine, but with an additional cost of time.

for pre-processing you can: Increase the DPI of the image, Resize the image and you can also check Bluring/Sharpening. High contrast betweent text and background is recognized much better.
after that try to de-noising it and binarize the image. It increases the accuracy quite good.