# Is there an OCR that can compare what it sees with a list of possible words I give it?

Tags: ocr

I am looking for an open-source OCR, but one where I can tell the program which letters I want it to look for. For example, if only letters and a comma are possible then I don't want the OCR to waste resources finding out whether it's a number. Also, I would like the OCR to output the possibilities of what it "thinks" it sees. For example, it there is an 'I', then the OCR might think that it's a lower-case 'L' instead, but it should also have 'I' as a close second. Basically I want the OCR to give me a list of possibilities and maybe the number to indicate how sure it is. So for example, it might say 'l': 55%, 'I':40%, other: 5%.

Another thing is I will know what text-type the letters are, i.e. Ariel, so there is no point in having the OCR comparing and contrasting different types of text.

Basically, I am writing a program where only a certain number of possibilities exist. For example, say I am using an OCR to read elements from the periodic table. There are only a limited number of elements, so the OCR should be able to guess that "HeIeun" is actually "Helium".

Is there anything like this, or do I have to do a ton a work coding this myself? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

you might want to take a look at the open source project [tesseract](http://code.google.com/p/tesseract-ocr/) developed by google, it gives very good results and has a lot of support for OCR.

For providing your own list of words to recognize text just Replace tessdata/eng.user-words with your own word list, in the same format - UTF8 text, one word per line.

To get very high accuracy chek [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11301343/how-do-i-improve-the-accuracy-of-the-ocr-text-from-tesseract) question.