# Improve Accuracy of Android TessBaseAPI (Tesseract) OCR

Tags: android, ocr, tesseract

I am using TessBaseAPI for OCR in my project with the help of following [this site](http://gaut.am/making-an-ocr-android-app-using-tesseract/). But, their result is 50% to 60% using a 5MP camera. I want to improve accuracy of my OCR.

VietOCR also use tesseract for OCR; their result is amazing and above 90% accurate. But accuracy of my application is not good.

Answer (score 3):

Hey so i had asked the question earlier at [How do I improve the accuracy of the OCR text from Tesseract?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11301343/how-do-i-improve-the-accuracy-of-the-ocr-text-from-tesseract)

After some researching i found out that you can improve the ratio by improving the image quality by some image enhancement algorithms ...if you want to have a look at a better OCR  app then you should try looking at this one : https://github.com/rmtheis/android-ocr

I havent used VietOCR so i don't really know what is the problem you have but even i have a 5MP camera and i also get the same accuracy rate so i think its not a phone problem as such but more of a library/image issue

Comment: Thanks for replying.
Dear have you used tessBaseAPIVar.init(dataPath, "eng", TessBaseAPI.OEM_TESSERACT_CUBE_COMBINED) option. When i include TessBaseAPI.OEM_TESSERACT_CUBE_COMBINED my application crashed.:(

Comment: Dear can you tell me, TessBaseAPI.OEM_TESSERACT_CUBE_COMBINED can improve my result?

Comment: THese are the lines of code which made my camera application interact with the tesseract API:

        TessBaseAPI baseapi = new TessBaseAPI();
     baseapi.init("/images/make_machine_example.jpg","eng");
     baseapi.setImage(bitmap);
     String recogtext = baseapi.getUTF8Text();
     baseapi.end();

Comment: I have not included the TessBaseAPI.OEM_TESSERACT_CUBE_COMBINED option and it works fine but the only problem is the accuracy rate of the application